# Rename files which have $'\r at end of file name (including recursive in folders) without using rename

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, rename

I have a ton of folders with jpg files in on a linux system. However I accidently moved them using a sh file that i made in windows.

Therefore instead of the files and structure being like this if running a ls command:

```
media/mugs/mug1.jpg
media/mugs/mug2.jpg
media/mugs/mug3.jpg
media/plates/plate1.jpg
media/plates/plate2.jpg
media/plates/plate3.jpg
```

Instead if I run a ls command, they show the following with a ' at the beginning and '$'\r' at the end:

```
media/mugs/'mug1.jpg'$'\r'
media/mugs/'mug2.jpg'$'\r'
media/mugs/'mug3.jpg'$'\r'
media/plates/'plate1.jpg'$'\r'
media/plates/'plate2.jpg'$'\r'
media/plates/'plate3.jpg'$'\r'
```

I do not have access to install programs, and therefore rename is not installed, I therefore only have access to built in ones such as find and mv

Much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test before using.

```
find media -name '*'$'\r' -print0 |
while IFS= read -r -d '' file
do    mv "$file" "${file%?}"
done
```

See `man bash` section *Parameter Expansion* for the syntax `${parameter%word}` to remove the last character, and `help read` for the `-r` `-d ''` options to read the filenames ending `\0` as produced by find's `print0`.

Comment: Thank you so much @meuh. That worked a treat, thank you.